# The linear operator $T_n: c_0\to c_{00}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the linear operator $T_n: c_0\to c_{00}$ given by
$$
T_n(\{x_k\}_k)=\left(x_1, \frac{x_2}{2},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{n}, 0,\cdots, \right)
$$
where $\{x_k\}_k\in c_0$ (i.e., $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k=0$). We take $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm.

I try to first prove that the $\{T_n\}$ is the Cauchy sequence. But this sequence is divergent in $B(c_0,c_{00})$.

---

For $m>n$,
$$
(T_n-T_m)(\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty})=\left(0,\cdots, 0, \frac{x_{n+1}}{n+1},\cdots, \frac{x_{m}}{m}, 0,\cdots\right)
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\|(T_n-T_m)(\{x_k\}\|}{\|\{x_k\}\|_{\infty}}=\frac{\dfrac{x_{l}}{l}}{x_h}\le \frac{1}{l}\le \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
where we take $\|(T_n-T_m)(\{x_k\}\|=\frac{x_{l}}{l}$ and $\sup|x_k|=x_{h}$

Moreover, I try to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} T_n=T$. I am stuck on here.

Comment: $
T(\{x_k\}_k)=(x_1, \frac{x_2}{2},\dots, \frac{x_n}{n}, \dots )
$

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what is the norm that you are working with?

Comment: I think there's a typo in whatever you're reading. It should be that $\|T_n - T_m\| = \frac{1}{n+1}$ (or perhaps $m < n$ instead).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In a previous post by this OP I pointed out that norm has to be specified. OP doesn't seem to care about our comments.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Here we use $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm.

Comment: Umm..operator norm? Evaluate $\sup _{\|x\|=1}\|(T_n-T_m)(x)\|$. What is $T$? Are you trying to show that $\lim T_n$ exists?

Comment: Adding that information as a comment is useless. You should edit your post instead.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes. You are right. But how to get it?

Comment: It is false that $\|T_n-T_m\|_\infty=\frac1{m+1}$. Actually, $\|T_n-T_m\|_\infty=\frac1{n+1}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes! You are right. Can I ask how to get $1/(n+1)$?

Comment: @Hermi Note that $$\|(T_n - T_m)(x)\| = \sup_{n+1 \le i \le m}\frac{|x_i|}{i} \le \sup_{n+1 \le i \le m}\frac{\|x\|}{i} = \frac{\|x\|}{n+1}.$$Now, it's just a matter of showing that it's achieved somewhere.

Comment: @ So this is as my update answer? Also, can we show that Tn is divergent?@TheoBendit

Comment: @Hermi You could proceed as in geetha's comment: while the $T$ they specified is not in $B(c_0, c_{00})$, you can isometrically isomorphically embed $B(c_0, c_{00})$ into $B(c_0, c_0)$ (by taking any $S \in B(c_0, c_{00})$ and composing on the left by the inclusion map from $c_{00}$ into $c_0$), in which geetha's $T$ makes sense. Show $T_n \to T$ in this larger space. If $T_n \to S \in B(c_0, c_{00})$, then $T_n \to S$ in $B(c_0, c_0)$ as well, which would contradict $T \notin B(x_0, c_{00})$ and the uniqueness of limits. Also, this argument would show $T_n$ is Cauchy, as it is convergent.

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry, I am lost in your answer. I am not sure how to show that $T$ is not in $B(c_0, c_{00})$. Is it possible to write an answer for this $T_n$ is divergent in $B(c_{0},c_{00})$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J : c_{00} \to c_0$ be the inclusion map from $c_{00}$ to $c_0$. Then $J$ is a linear isometry (not surjective) from $c_{00}$ into $c_0$ (since $c_{00}$ is just a subspace of $c_0$, inheriting the same norm). Define a map $\varphi : B(c_0, c_{00}) \to B(c_0, c_0)$ by
$$\varphi : T \in B(c_0, c_{00}) \mapsto J \circ T \in B(c_0, c_0).$$
The map is not complicated at all: take any bounded linear $T : c_0 \to c_{00}$, and pretend the codomain was the larger space $c_0$ instead of $c_{00}$.

Note that $J \circ T$ is bounded and linear, as it is the composition of two bounded, linear maps. Moreover, $\varphi$ is linear, since addition distributes over composition/multiplication of linear maps. It is also an isometry (not surjective):
$$\|\varphi T\| = \sup_{x \in c_0} \|\varphi Tx\|_{c_0} = \sup_{x \in c_0} \|JTx\|_{c_0} = \sup_{x \in c_0} \|Tx\|_{c_{00}} = \|T\|.$$

Let
$$T : c_0 \to c_0 : (x_n)_n \mapsto \left(\frac{x_n}{n}\right)_n$$

Now, I claim that $\varphi T_n \to T$, under the operator norm on $B(c_0, c_0)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\|(T - \varphi T_n)(x)\|_\infty &= \left\|\left(\underbrace{0, 0, \ldots, 0}_{\text{n times}}, \frac{x_{n+1}}{n+1}, \frac{x_{n+2}}{n+2}, \ldots \right)\right\|_\infty \\
&= \sup_{k > n}\frac{|x_k|}{k} \le \sup_{k > n} \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{k} = \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{n+1}.
\end{align*}
As such, $\|T - \varphi T_n\| \le \frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (actually, equality is possible, but not necessary).

Thus, $\varphi T_n$ converges, and hence is Cauchy. Since $\varphi$ is a linear isometry,
$$\|T_n - T_m\| = \|\varphi T_n - \varphi T_m\| \to 0 \quad \text{as } m, n \to \infty.$$
Thus, $T_n$ is also Cauchy.

Let us suppose $T_n$ converges to $S \in B(c_0, c_{00})$. Then, by the continuity of $\varphi$ (since it is an isometry), we have $\varphi T_n \to \varphi S$. But, $\varphi T_n \to T$, so $T = \varphi S$. But, $\varphi S$ must have a range contained in $c_{00}$, whereas, $T(1, 1, \ldots) = (1, 1/2, \ldots) \notin c_{00}$. Thus, we have a contradiction: $T$ is Cauchy, but $T$ does not converge.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Can I ask the reason for "Thus, $\varphi T_n$ converges, and hence in Cauchy"? Do you use that $B(c_0, c_0)$ is complete? Do we need to prove that?

Comment: Also, I have a question about the last statement "But, $\varphi S$ must have a range contained in $c_{00}$". Why can we say that? Here $S\in B(c_0, c_{00})$, so  it seems that $\varphi S\in B(c_0, c_0)$? I a little bit confused where we get the contradiction. Here $T(1,1,\dots,)=(1,1/2,\dots)\in c_{00}$, this is right with our assumption. And $\varphi S(1,1,\dots,)=(1,1/2,\dots)\in c_{00}$. I do not find problem whit that?

Comment: First question: No completeness needed. I just wrote down a bounded linear operator on $c_0$ called $T$, and showed $\varphi T$ converges to it, essentially by definition. Second question: The range of the map $S$ is contained in its codomain $c_{00}$. We also have that $\varphi S = J \circ S$, where $J$ is the inclusion map of $c_{00}$ into $c_0$, essentially increasing the codomain of $S$ to all of $c_0$. But, this doesn't increase the range. If we apply $S$ to any $x \in c_0$, then it produces $Sx \in c_{00}$, and then $J(Sx) = Sx \in c_{00}$, so the range of $\varphi S$ is in $c_{00}$.

Comment: I am still confused about that. (1) Why $J$ is inclusion map (well, I did not know what is the definition of the inclusion)? (2) For $Sx\in c_{00}$, why can we get $J(Sx)\in c_{00}$ by the inclusion map $J$?

Comment: I just check the definition of inclusion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map. It seems that it did not say that $J(c_{00})\subset c_{00}$?

Comment: @Hermi Suppose $A \subseteq B$. The inclusion map $J : A \to B$ is defined like this: $J(x) = x$ for all $x \in A$. It's basically the identity map $I : A \to A$, except the codomain is larger. So, to answer (2), $Sx$ and $J(Sx)$ are the same, by the definition of $J$. As $Sx \in c_{00}$ (since $c_{00}$ is the codomain of $S$), and $J(Sx) = Sx$, we must also have $J(Sx) \in c_{00}$ as well; it is the same vector as $Sx$ after all!

Comment: To answer (1), all I'm trying to convey with $\varphi$ here is to take a bounded linear map $S : c_0 \to c_{00}$, and, without changing what the map does to any vector in $c_0$, pretend it was a map $S : c_0 \to c_0$ instead. We can do this, because $c_{00}$ is just a subset of $c_0$. As it stands, from our definition, we can't quite say $S \in B(c_0, c_0)$, because it has a different codomain to the $c_0$ specified, but we sort of can, because its range is still contained in $c_0$. To make this official, we compose with the inclusion map: it doesn't change the output, just the codomain.